# Available wifi network list missing and intermittent wired connection

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, ethernet

Never used Ubuntu before but fancied trying it out.
Installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on a 10yo dell Inspiron laptop. 
Wifi was working on windows 7 yesterday but after getting rid of windows and solely installing Ubuntu on it it sometimes allows Ethernet connection but I have no list of wifi networks at all. 
I will have wired connection and then when I restart it sometimes tells me I  disconnected.
Any ideas how to sort both out? 
In the driver updates it tells me to update the Broadcom driver but still no wifi even after a reboot. 
I hope that made sense??

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

alan@alan-MM061:~$ rfkill list

alan@alan-MM061:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

After `bcmwl-kernel-source` install:

```
alan@alan-MM061:~$ lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron 6400 [1028:01af]
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832]
--
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Its showing as  - 0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: Sorry, also was there something wrong with the question?

Comment: Please post additional information to your question. I did that for you this time, but please do it yourself.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list` and `iwconfig`.

Comment: Run the rest of commands. And also add output of `uname -a`.

Comment: The last command does things but gives no output if it is OK. Does wifi work now? Please give again `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Did you run `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to start with gedit. Everything else is already installed.

Comment: YOU do not ADD it to text file, but replace its contents with this text.  Gedit will open a text file with similar contents. You will need to edit it or just replace the content. Then save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well documented that, despite Broadcom's README, bcmwl-kernel-source does *not* work for your device. I suggest you do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firmware-b43-installer
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: It does not work with b43. That's what we started from. If `wl` does not work as well, then we'll see. But do not confuse OP now.

Comment: We shall see, indeed.

Comment: Well I then tried Chili555 suggestion and re-booted and it worked straight away.....Thanks so much for the fix and thank you pilot6 for all your help mate!

Comment: Now I am sure that for 4311 b43 should be used too. +1